# Apache doesn't log remoteIP when RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For is present

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm using Apache/2.4.27

Within the VirtualHost I'm forwarding the remote client IP header from the Loadbalancer with:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

Which is needed by the application served by that Virtualhost.

This is the log format within the main httpd.conf context.

```
LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

When I have the RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For listed within the virtualhost, Apache stops writting the remote-client IP into logs.

When I remove it from the VirtualHost, the remote-client IP starts appearing again within the logs.

Any ideas why the `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For` doesn't play with `(%{X-Forwarded-For}i)` from the LogFormat ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restore %a to that format if you're going to use mod_remoteip.

In bugzilla, mod_remoteip fills in %a while it
removes from %{X-Forwarded-For}i.  So in a simple case with one
trusted proxy, %a will hold the value used to see in
X-Forwarded-For because of mod_remoteip

Answer (score 5):

**Proxy Layer (Nginx)**

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
```

**Backend Layer (Apache)**

```
# Log format config
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" common
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common env=forwarded

# Header config
RemoteIPHeader X-Real-IP
RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
RemoteIPInternalProxy 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.11
```

Description:

**proxy_set_header** - directive sets headers that nginx sends to backend; so in this example We sends two variables (to headers): `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-IP`

**X-Forwarded-For** - on the proxy side it must be set that this header should be passed to backends and accessible from their layer

**X-Real-IP** - it does not affect the required variables on the web page but we leave it enabled so that the Apache server places the client's address in the logs (you also need to set the log format itself):

```
### X-Real-IP enabled
172.217.20.206 - - [03/Jun/2017:11:12:11 +0200] "GET /tls-check.php?9832 HTTP/1.0" 200 1409
### X-Real-IP disabled
172.16.21.11 - - [03/Jun/2017:15:12:49 +0200] "GET /tls-check.php?13266 HTTP/1.0" 200 1448
```

**Curl**

```
:~$ curl -H Cache-Control: no-cache -ks https://example.com/tls-check.php?${RANDOM} | grep "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR\|HTTP_X_REAL_IP\|SERVER_ADDR\|REMOTE_ADDR"
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 172.217.20.206
[HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 172.217.20.206
[SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.10.100
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 192.168.10.10
```

**tls_check.php**

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '</pre>';
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried, this doesn't work for me. Can you perhaps explain what is this for SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded ?

Comment: Hi! If the above tips are not suitable for you, please provide a configuration (if possible) that you use.

Comment: True, thanks. I'm not using NGINX. I'm using AWS Application Loadbalancer, where I don't have the possibility to set headers as X-real-IP

Comment: I do not use LB from AWS, maybe it will be useful for you: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/log-client-ip-load-balancer-apache/

Comment: Yes, I know this documentation and I have it like they are reffering, but my original problem is the combination of RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For, when I remove it, it logs the remote IP

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Replaced %h to %a

```
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing it between `\" \"` the same as it is done wirh Referer and User-Agent headers

```
LogFormat "%h \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Comment: nope, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer to get formatting, instead of a comment on @DaWe4444 's correct answer.  Though it is correct, I didn't understand it at first.

To elucidate, my final config wound up as:

```
RemoteIPHeader Client-ip
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy my.proxy.ip.address
```

which works for a an Apache Traffic Server upstream on Apache 2.4.25 on Debian.

I needed to change the combined log format line in apache2.conf as so:

```
-LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
+LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Some recipes out there call for switching the log format based on X-Forwarded-For headers, but mod_remoteip unsets that header, so those don't work with mod_remoteip.  Since %h incurs a DNS lookup cost (%a is just client IP) I was surprised to find it as a default.  Back in the day disabling DNS on queries was one of the first things every apache admin would do; log file analyzers will handle that part.

Comment: From what I can tell, subsequent `RemoteIPHeader` declarations override the previous ones, so in your current example, `Client-ip` would be lost.